# VBA Code is returning #value after adding one additional input, how can I fix?

Tags: vba, return-value

Thank you in advance for your help. My original code without the LGDCategory variable/input works but when try to add the additional variable LGDCategory the code is returning #value. Any thoughts how to fix this? The actual code is very long with many ifthen statements. If you need additional information please let me know. Thank you again.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text
Function Default(RiskCategory As String, LGDCategory As String, Rating As String, Duration As Double)
SDuration2 = WorksheetFunction.Max(1, Duration)
Dim Duration_rounded_up As Double, Duration_rounded_down As Double
Duration_rounded_up = WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(Duration, 0)
Duration_rounded_down = WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(Duration, 0)
Dim PDCumulative As Double

If RiskCategory = "Corporate" And LGDCategory = "1stLienBond" Then
    If Rating = "AAA" Then
        If SDuration2 >= 1 And SDuration2 < 2 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.000102 - 0) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 1) + 0
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 2 And SDuration2 < 3 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.000102 - 0.000102) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 2) + 0.000102
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 3 And SDuration2 < 4 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.00029 - 0.000102) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 3) + 0.000102
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 4 And SDuration2 < 5 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.000801 - 0.00029) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 4) + 0.00029
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 5 And SDuration2 < 6 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.001296 - 0.000801) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 5) + 0.000801
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 6 And SDuration2 < 7 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.001815 - 0.001296) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 6) + 0.001296
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 7 And SDuration2 < 8 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.002362 - 0.001815) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 7) + 0.001815
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 8 And SDuration2 < 9 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.002937 - 0.002362) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 8) + 0.002362
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 9 And SDuration2 < 10 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.003543 - 0.002937) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 9) + 0.002937
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 10 And SDuration2 < 11 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.004182 - 0.003543) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 10) + 0.003543
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 11 And SDuration2 < 12 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.004854 - 0.004182) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 11) + 0.004182
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 12 And SDuration2 < 13 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.005535 - 0.004854) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 12) + 0.004854
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 13 And SDuration2 < 14 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.005915 - 0.005535) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 13) + 0.005535
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 14 And SDuration2 < 15 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.00632 - 0.005915) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 14) + 0.005915
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 15 And SDuration2 < 16 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.00675 - 0.00632) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 15) + 0.00632
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 16 And SDuration2 < 17 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.007206 - 0.00675) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 16) + 0.00675
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 17 And SDuration2 < 18 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.007365 - 0.007206) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 17) + 0.007206
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 18 And SDuration2 < 19 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.007365 - 0.007365) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 18) + 0.007365
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 19 And SDuration2 < 20 Then
            PDCumulative = (0.007365 - 0.007365) / (Duration_rounded_up - Duration_rounded_down) * (Duration - 19) + 0.007365
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 19 And SDuration2 < 20 Then
            PDCumulative = 0.007365
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
        ElseIf SDuration2 >= 20 And SDuration2 < 50 Then
            PDCumulative = 1 - (1 - 0.007365) * ((1 - 0.007365) / (1 - 0.007365)) ^ (Duration - 20)
            Default = -(1 - (1 - PDCumulative) ^ (1 / Duration)) * 0.45396 * 10000
End If
End If
End If
```

Comment: What programming language is this? Please add an appropriate tag. It looks like VB.Net, but I'm not sure. Notice that if `LGDCategory` is not `"1stLienBond"`, then nothing is executed and the function fails to return a value. Maybe that's what you're seeing. Some stepping through the code in a debugger should make it clear what's going on.

Comment: VBA. Stepping through the code has not identified any issues

Comment: Notice that sometimes the function returns without ever performing a `Default = (something)`

Comment: any thoughts how to fix it?

Comment: Make sure every code path sets a return value.